# This page can’t be displayed - Asp.Net MVC3 on IIS 8.5 Windows Server 2012

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, windows-server-2012, iis-8.5

I have an MVC 3 application and WCF service to be deployed in IIS 8.5 installed on Windows Server. I have checked all the prerequisites installed for IIS 8.5. After the deployment when I try to access the .svc files, I get "This page can't be displayed". 
The have verified the below conditions.

APP POOL:

1.) The app pool is set to "Integrated" mode and targetted to V4.0.

2.) Identity is set to "ApplicationPoolIdentity" and enabled 32 bit
applications.

BINDINGS:

1.) Provided a different port"88" and ip address is configured.

PERMISSIONS:

1.) Full access has been provided for the below mentioned users.

a.) IUSR

b.) IIS_IUSRS

c.) DefaultAppPool(This is the app pool that has
   been assigned).

I am struck with this, Please let me know for anything that needs to be included.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the error page when accessing from localhost. There should be some hint what might be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have HTTP Activation checked for WCF Service under IIS features. If not you need to enable that from server manager add roles/features wizard. Please refer to the image attached. [image]

Comment: Yes, HTTP Activation is installed. Indeed all the WCF services were installed.

Comment: Yes for both 3.5 and 4.5 its installed.

Comment: Are you able to access these WCF endpoints via any client like WCF test client or fiddler?

Comment: No, the end point is not even up or accessible, I only get page cannot be displayed or web page not available.